# Missing artifact org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.0.0.Beta7 - Hibernate tutorial

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I'm going through the Hibernate tutorial at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html_single/ .  I create a new project, and use the pom.xml given in the example in Ch. 1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>First Hibernate Tutorial</name>

<build>
     <!-- we dont want the version to be part of the generated war file name -->
     <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on the servlet api. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I'm using JBoss 7 - I get the error Missing artifact org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.0.0.Beta7 .  I tried to include jandex as a dependency but I still get this error.  I confirmed that jandex exists in /modules/org/jboss/jandex.  How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 10):

Add the following to your pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
  <!-- For hibernate support -->
  <repository>
   <id>jboss</id>
   <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```